# FAIL: alsa/Makefile dependency check: $(shell pkg-config --libs alsa)

Tags: testing, linux-kernel, automated-tests

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. When I run  `./kselftest_deps.sh gcc` in `./linux-5.19.0/tools/testing/selftests`, it shows the following:

```
FAIL: alsa/Makefile dependency check: $(shell
FAIL: alsa/Makefile dependency check: pkg-config
FAIL: alsa/Makefile dependency check: --libs
FAIL: alsa/Makefile dependency check: alsa)
FAIL: alsa/Makefile dependency check: $(shell
FAIL: alsa/Makefile dependency check: pkg-config
FAIL: alsa/Makefile dependency check: --libs
FAIL: alsa/Makefile dependency check: alsa)
```

I check the `alsa/Makefile`, it has the following two lines:

```
CFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --cflags alsa)
LDLIBS += $(shell pkg-config --libs alsa)
```

While we all know that for **pkg-config** to be effective, there must be a file named `alsa.pc` in the specified path. But I can't find `alsa.pc` in either `./alsa` directory or in the whole linux kernel source directory.
I googled and tried to install **alsa** by `sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev` and other relevant commands. It still generates the same output.

So how to solve this issue?

I comment the two lines in the Makefile and this time `./kselftest_deps.sh gcc` yields no **FAIL** about **alsa** . Is this a solution?

Comment: The line `FAIL: alsa/Makefile dependency check: $(shell` means that checker doesn't find the library named `$(shell`. The checker simply doesn't parse the `$(shell ...)` expression.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I run $echo $SHELL  returns $/bin/bash. Is it enough?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Even if I removed shell in Makefile, it still shows FAIL: $(pkg-config --libs alsa)

Comment: @Tsyvarev Actually when I commented out LDLIBS += $(shell pkg-config --libs alsa), there is no FAIL.

Comment: "I run $echo $SHELL returns $/bin/bash. Is it enough?" - Enough for what? Again, the checker even does **not try** to parse the `$(shell ...)` expression. It is absolutely unrelated whether your shell is bash or whatever else. BTW, according to the comments in the checker script [kselftest_deps.sh](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.11/source/tools/testing/selftests/kselftest_deps.sh#L138), it expects calling `pkg-config` only when variable `VAR_LDLIBS` is assigned. Probably, `alsa` tests forget to follow that convention... or cannot follow it.

Comment: The alsa selftests seem to be new since the 5.17 kernel, but they don't seem to work on that kernel or any later ones!

Comment: However, I don't think the `./kselftest_deps.sh` script is meant to be run directly.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You mentioned VAR_LDLIBS, but the alsa Makefile uses LDLIBS. There is no VAR_LDLIBS in alsa Makefile.

Comment: @li_jessen: This is exactly what I meant: The checker doesn't expect usage of `pkg-config` in assignment of variable `LDLIBS`, like in `alsa/Makefile`. That usage is expected only when variable `VAR_LDLIBS` is assigned.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't see the kselftest_deps.sh says that pkg-config is expected when VAR_LDLIBS is assigned. It just says to filter out the makefile where pkg-config is used in VAR_LOLIBS assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an email to the relevant maintainers and got a reply saying that he thinks it's bug failing to parse the `$(shell pkg-config --libs alsa)`.